# ngrok not working with mamp

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro, ngrok

I am using `MAMP Pro` as development environment. I have used `ngrok` with `MAMP` before. however in this particular situation it redirects from the `ngrok` url to my local url and https is not available .

my local server is `e-kyc.dev` and im using `ngrok http -host-header=e-kyc.dev 80` to run `ngrok`.
[image]
however when im using `https:/a95118d9.ngrok.io` it loads the welcome page(wihtout ssl) and once I click on a link it will redirect to a local url like `e-kyc.dev/login` instead of `https:/a95118d9.ngrok.io/login`

**NOTE:** my server works as expected locally, also functioning properly while using xip.io(for Lan) and selfsigned SSL.

Comment: I know it's a month late, but, I hope my answer below is helpful.

Answer (score 47):

for me the option --host-header=rewrite did work out:

```
./ngrok http --host-header=rewrite myname.test:80
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: `-host-header=rewrite` saved the day - but what does it do ?

Comment: is now --host-header=rewrite

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to fix this:

First, the free way:

1. In MAMP, go to your hosts and turn off the built in SSL.
2. In MAMP, for that host, change the port for that host to something other than 80 (I used 8080).
3. Open your terminal and navigate to the public directory for the web app. Run `ngrok http 8080` from inside the public directory.
4. Grab the https path provided by ngrok and you should have success.

Next, the paid way:

1. Upgrate ngrok to the pro or business plan
2. Use tls `ngrok tls -subdomain=encrypted 443`

... I'm assuming that the OP wants to go the free route. Hope this helps!

Comment: I encountered the same problem, and your answer doesnt seem to solve it ..

Comment: Does not solves. It's actually the problem described by the OP.